# Ruby-on-Rails: how to publicly expose a sub-directory other than the "public" folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was thinking to override this:

ActionController::Base.asset_host = "assets.example.com" 
but we still want the public folder available, can we have like multiple asset_host or there's other way around for this?

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

It's still the same public folder available with asset host. The reason for assets hosts is that you can have several asset hostnames making download speedier because there are some limitations on how many connections a client can have to the same web server.

"Browsers typically open at most two simultaneous connections to a single host, which means your assets often have to wait for other assets to finish downloading."

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html